# How can I edit a file on EC2 directly from my localhost?

Tags: ssh, development-environment, amazon-ec2

I have a batch script on an EC2 instance that I would like to be able to edit directly from my desktop's text editor.

What is a good method of doing so easily?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a file browser program that supports SFTP and connect using your AWS SSH credentials.  [CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch/) on Mac or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) on Windows are good options.